# Epimorphism from GL(2,Z) to GL(2,Z)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, hopfian

Is there an epimorphism $f\colon \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})\to \mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ which is not injective? Here, $\mathrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is the group of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices with integer entries.

*Added.* The answer is no: this group is Hopfian. I know a proof in which it is shown that this group is finitely generated (easy) and residually finite(tricky).
I suspect that there exists another more "elementary" proof if we use isomorphisms of this group.

I'd really like to see such a proof and so I would be thankfull if someone wrote it (if there exists of course).

Comment: Please try to use mark-up. It makes things easier to read.

Comment: Why is it tricky to show that $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb Z)$ is residually finite? You automagically have lots of surjections $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb Z)\twoheadrightarrow \operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb Z_p)$ for all primes $p$, for example...

Comment: I mean it's the tricky part of this proof.

Comment: I think Mariano's remark means you don't need to know $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Steve - you do need to know finite generation if you want to deduce that it's non-Hopfian.

Comment: Regarding other possible proofs: there's another proof that free groups are Hopfian, using Nielsen transformations.  It's given in Lyndon & Schupp.  Now, $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is virtually free.  It may be possible to use these two facts to come up with a different proof, though I don't know how.

Comment: @Henry Wilton: Right, sorry, I was thinking of residually finite.

Answer (score 9):

The Maltsev proof is in fact quite easy.  Let me give the proofs of the two relevant results.

**Theorem:** If $G$ is finitely generated and residually finite then $G$ is Hopfian, ie every epimorphism is an isomorphism.

*Proof:* Suppose not; let $f:G\to G$ be an epimorphism with some non-trivial $g$ in its kernel.  For each $n$ let $g_n$ be such that $f^n(g_n)=g$.  Let $q: G\to Q$ be a map to a finite group such that $q(g)\neq 1$.  Now $q\circ f^n$ kills $g_{n+1}$ but not $g_n$, so the homomorphisms $q\circ f^n$ are all distinct.  But there are only finitely many homomorphisms from a finitely generated group to a finite group, so this is a contradiction. *QED*

A Mariano indicates, the proof that $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is residually finite is also easy.

**Theorem:** $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is residually finite.

*Proof:* Let $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, thought of as a matrix.  Choose some prime $p$ that does not divide all of the entries of $A-I$.  The reduction homomorphism $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})\to GL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is a map to a finite group that does not kill $A$. *QED*

See - easy!

Answer (score 4):

No.  It is a theorem of Maltsev (or Malcev depending on how the name is translated into Latin characters) that every finitely generated subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, i.e. a linear group, is residually finite and, hence, Hopfian, which means that every epimorphism is injective.

Comment: That's the proof I already know of.