# $\langle X|\emptyset\rangle\ncong\langle X|R\rangle$ for finitely presented groups (exercise in Massey)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, hopfian

Let $:F_n$ denote the free group of rank $n$. How can I solve the exercise 7.6.3.(b), page 234, in Massey's *Algebraic Topology*?

[image]

I'm guessing there's been made a mistake and (b) actually reads "If $G$ is a free group of finite rank and $N$ is a **nontrivial** normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/N$ is not isomorphic to $G$", since $N=\{1\}$ gives a counterexample.

So, how can I prove:

$$\{1\}\neq N\trianglelefteq F_n\Longrightarrow F_n\ncong F_n/N?$$

I don't know how to use 7.6.3:

If $f:F_n\rightarrow F_n$ is a surjective homomorphism, it is an isomorphism.

Comment: did you prove the first part of the statement yet (what precedes the questions $(a)$ and $(b)$)?

Comment: @Olivier: yes, just use the Grushko theorem: If $\varphi\!:F_X\!\rightarrow\!\amalg_{i\in I}G_i$ is a surjective homomorphism, then there exists a decomposition $F_X=\amalg_{i\in I}F_{X_i}$ such that $\forall i\!\in\!I\!:\:\varphi(F_{X_i})=G_i$. But how can I use that to prove (b)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of your question, that if $f: F_{\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}}\rightarrow F_{\{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}}$ is an epimorphism then it is an isomorphism is a property called Hopfian. It is a very nice property, and I, personally, refuse to believe that any group is non-Hopfian (I know that Baumslag-Solitar groups are, as in $\mathbb{Z}^{\infty}$, but that doesn't mean I *believe* they are...). Some background on Hopfian groups can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/79907/10513).

Now, the part (b) is just a basic application of the first isomorphism theorem ($G/\ker\phi\cong \operatorname{im}\phi$). If $F_n\cong F_n/N$ then there exists some epimorphism, $\phi: F_n\rightarrow F_n$, which has kernel $N$ (why?). As $F_n$ is Hopfian, $N$ must be trivial, and your done.

Really, the tricky bit is proving that finitely generated free groups are Hopfian.
Now, a group $G$ is *residually finite* if for every non-trivial element $w$ there exists a finite group $H_w$ such that there exists $\phi: G\rightarrow H_w$ an epimorphism, and $\phi(w)\neq 1$. If $G$ is finitely generated and residually finite then $G$ is Hopfian. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/672199/10513) for a proof. Therefore, if we can prove that free groups are residually finite then we have shown that they are Hopfian. Whoop! The neatest proof of the residual finiteness of free groups that I know of goes as follows:

1. If $G$ is finitely generated and residually finite then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is residually finite.
2. As $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\cong \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})$, we have that $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is residually finite.
3. $F(a, b)\leq \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, by the following embedding. $$\begin{align*}a&\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\0&1\end{array}\right)\\b&\mapsto\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\2&1\end{array}\right)\end{align*}$$
4. As subgroups of residually finite groups are residually finite, $F(a, b)$ is residually finite.
5. Every countable free group embeds into $F(a, b)$, hence every countable free group is residually finite.

Every step here is non-trivial, but not too hard. They are also all interesting. Steps (2)-(5) are all well-documented and probably covered in whatever course you are studying (I think John Meier's book *Graphs, groups and trees* is probably the best reference for these, especially step (3) where he uses the ping-pong lemma). So I need to tell you about step (1)*. However, step (1) is why this is so wonderful and beautiful and amazing. Step (1) appeared in a 1-page (not including references) paper of G. Baumslag. His proof is cunning and simple.

**Theorem** (G. Baumslag).
Suppose $G$ is finitely generated and residually finite. Then $G$ has residually finite automorphism group.

The proof uses the following definition: a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is called \emph{characteristic} if $\phi(N)=N$ for all $\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.

*Begin by noting that if $H\leq_fG$ then there exists a characteristic subgroup $N$ of $G$ with $N\leq_fH$, which is obtained by intersecting the subgroups of index $|G:H|=:n$. The resulting group is characteristic because automorphisms preserve index, and it has finite index because there are only finitely many subgroups of index $n$ as $G$ is finitely generated.*

*Now, suppose $\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is non-trivial. We shall find a finite group $K$ such that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\rightarrow\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ and $\phi$ is not mapped to the identity under this homomorphism. To do this, note that as $\phi$ is non-trivial there exists some $g\in G$ such that $g^{-1}\phi(g)\neq 1$. Choose $x\neq g^{-1}\phi(g)$. Then there exists some characteristic subgroup $N_x\unlhd_f G$ with $x\not\in N_x$. Set $K=G/N_x$. Then $\phi$ acts on $G/N_x$ because $N_x$ is characteristic, and as $g^{-1}\phi(g)\not\in N_x$ we have that $gN_x\neq \phi(gN_x)$. Therefore, the action of $\phi$ on $K$ is non-trivial, as required.*

*This answer is basically an excuse to tell you about step (1) and the theorem of Baumslag. It is one of my all-time favourite proofs!

**Note:** An alternative proof that $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is residually finite, so an alternative to steps (1) and (2) combined, is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17301/10513).

Comment: From [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group): A group $G$ *Hopfian* if every epimorphism $G \rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism. Equivalently, a group is Hopfian iff it is not isomorphic to any of its proper quotients. A group G is *co-Hopfian* if every monomorphism $G \rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism. Equivalently, $G$ is not isomorphic to any of its proper subgroups. Hmm very interesting, thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain how I should use the first isomorphism theorem to find and epimorphism $F_n\rightarrow F_n$ with kernel $N$? By "first isomorphism theorem", do you actually mean "Factorization Theorem" (every $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ with $N\leq ker\varphi$ factors uniquely through $G/N$) or "Homomorphism Theorem" ($A/ker\varphi\cong im\varphi$) or really the "first isomorphism theorem" ($A/B\cong\!(A/C)/(B/C)$)?

Comment: I'd guess you just precompose with the quotient projection.

Comment: Ah, if $\pi:F_n\rightarrow F_n/N$ is the quotient projection and $f:F/N\rightarrow F_n$ is the isomorphism, then $f\circ \pi$ is the desired homomorphism $F_n\rightarrow F_n$ with kernel $N$. Don't really know what the isomorphism theorems have to do with it. Thanks @Miha.

Comment: The first Isomorphism theorem (according to Wiki, and every book I have ever read) is $G/ker\phi\cong im\phi$. It's the other two that come in an arbitrary order I've always thought...

Comment: @Miha: Can one remove the finiteness condition, i.e. *is every free group Hopfian*, i.e. *is every epimorphism $F_X\rightarrow F_X$ an isomorphism*? I'm trying to use Grushko's theorem: if $\varphi:F_X\rightarrow\amalg_{i\in I}G_i$ is epimorphism, then $\exists$ decomposition $F_X=\amalg_{i\in I}F_{X_i}$} $(X=\cup_{i\in I}X_i)$ such that $\forall i\in I:\varphi(F_{X_i})=G_i$. Is epimorphism $F_\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow F_\mathbb{Z}$ an isomorphism? The problem: one can decompose $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{n\}$ or $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}\{n,-n\}$ where $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Z}|$.

Comment: @Leon: Free groups of infinite rank are not hopfian: pick a proper subset $B$ of the set of original generators $A$ of the same cardinality. Define a map by sending $A\setminus B$ to 1 and $B$ to $A$ (bijectively) and extend this to a noninjective epimorphism.

Comment: @Miha - it is easier than that. Just send any one of the generators to the identity!

Comment: @Swlabr: that's just a special case when $|B|=1$.

Comment: I know, but giving $B$ arbitrary size is just overkill...

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $F = F_{n}$.  The mapping from $F$ upon the quotient group $F/N$ which takes $f$ in $F$ to the coset $fN$ is an epimorphism; call it $\eta$.  Suppose there is an isomorphism $\varphi$ from $F/N$ to $F$.  Composing these two maps, we get an epimorphism $\varphi\circ\eta : F\to F/N\to F$ of $F$ upon itself.  Now use the first part to conclude that it is an isomorphism.  In particular, the isomorphism $\varphi\circ\eta$ is injective, so $\eta$ is injective.  Therefore, the kernel $N$ of $\eta$ is trivial.