# Example of not so simple group ??

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Help me with an example of a group having subgroups but it doesn't admit a normal subgroup.. ??

The alternate definition of simple groups using non trivial homomorphic image. Searching for a map that doesn't have a non trivial kernal ??

Comment: *Every* group admits two normal subgroups, $1$ and itself. Now, as nontrivial normal subgroups goes, that's another story.

Comment: Better to not try to be clever in the title - I expected that you wanted something other than a simple group. BE direct, particular in forums where there are lots of foreign readers.

Answer (score 6):

One classic example is [$A_5$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group%3aA5), which has plenty of non-trivial subgroups, none of which are normal.  In fact, this is the smallest suitable example.

Answer (score 5):

All the other examples are of *finite* simple groups. However, there do exist infinite simple groups. One of the best known is Richard Thompson's group $T$. It contains a very interesting group, called $F$, as a subgroup. I'll just define these groups here. If you want a more complete introduction then look at [this](http://www.ams.org/notices/201108/rtx110801112p.pdf) ams "What is..." article by J. W. Cannon and W. J. Floyd. If you want a proof that this group is simple then you should look up [the article "Introductory notes on Richard Thompson's groups" by Cannon, Floyd and Parry](http://people.math.binghamton.edu/matt/thompson/cfp.pdf). These notes of Cannon, Floyd and Parry are the standard reference for Richard Thompson's groups $F$, $T$ and $V$.

There are three groups introduced by Thompson in 1965, $F<T<V$, and I believe he did not publish his constructions although he did prove that $T$ and $V$ are both simple. I'll define $F$, and use this to define $T$. The definition of $V$ is more complicated so I'll leave you to look it up in one of the above references.

**The group $F$**: The group $F$ is the set consisting of piecewise linear homeomorphisms from the closed unit interval to itself which are differentiable at all but finitely many dyadic rational numbers $\frac{a}{2^b}$, and such that at intervals of differentiability the derivatives are powers of two.

This means that every element of $F$ has the following form. Note that there are only finitely many intervals, each of whose maximum and minimum is a dyadic rational number. The function on each interval has the form $2^ax+\frac{b}{2^c}$, $a, b, c\in\mathbb{Z}$, $c>0$.
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+\frac12&1\leq x\leq \frac14\\
\frac{x}{2}+\frac18&\frac14\leq x\leq \frac12\\
\frac{x}{4}+\frac{1}{16}&\frac14\leq x\leq \frac12\\
2x+\frac12&\frac34\leq x\leq \frac78\\
x+1&\frac{29}{32}\leq x\leq 1
\end{cases}$$
One useful way of thinking about $F$ is as a subgroup of automorphisms of the circle, but where we fix a common point. This works because when you pin together the ends of the unit interval you get a circle, and the elements of $F$ fix this pinning point.

**The group $T$**: The group $T$ is the analogue of $F$ to the circle, so if you additionally allow $F$ to move the pinning point $0=1$. So $T$ is $F$ with rotation. More formally, consider $S^1$ as the unit interval $[0, 1]$, then the group $T$ is the set consisting of piecewise linear homeomorphisms from $S^1$ to itself which are differentiable at all but finitely many dyadic rational numbers $\frac{a}{2^b}$, and such that at intervals of differentiability the derivatives are powers of two.

View $F$ as automorphisms of the circle. Then the group $T$ is simply the group generated by $F$ along with the half-rotation map $x\mapsto x+\frac12\pmod1$, which can be described as follows,
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
x+\frac12&1\leq x\leq \frac12\\
x-\frac12&\frac12\leq x\leq 1
\end{cases}$$
Theorem 5.8 and Corollary 5.9 of Cannon, Floyd and Parry's notes combine to prove that $T$ is simple (although this proof uses a different additional generator for $T$ from the one I state, above).

**Some more on $F$**: These three groups, of which I have defined two, are interesting and much studied. Indeed, I have heard people referred to as "Thompson's group people", and and career's have been built on these groups! Perhaps the most studied of all though if $F$, the only one which is not simple. From the ams article, *The group F does not fit easily into standard categories. It is non-Abelian and torsion-free and contains a free semigroup on two generators, yet it contains no non-Abelian free subgroup. It is not a matrix group. Every subgroup of F is either finite rank free Abelian or contains an infinite-rank free Abelian subgroup.*

One of the current open problems on $F$ is its amenability. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26821/is-thompsons-group-f-amenable) old MO question and its answers. I have been led to believe that this question is really only interesting because it has garnered so many incorrect answers!

Answer (score 3):

An example of a group $G$ that has lots of subgroups (15 conjugacy classes of subgroups, 179 total subgroups), but with only the two obvious normal subgroups $1$ and $G$, is the group $G$ of three by three invertible matrices with 0-1 entries and arithmetic operations done mod 2. $G$ has order $(2^3-1)(2^3-2)(2^3-4) = 168$.

Answer (score 3):

We must look to nonabelian groups since every subgroup of an abelian group will be normal.  The example that comes to mind quickly is the alternating group $A_n$ for all $n \geq 5$.

$PSL(3, 2)$ is the second smallest example behind $A_5$ of a group with subgroups, none of whom are normal.

[http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group:PSL(3,2)](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group%3aPSL%283,2%29)

Comment: $C_2$ is a perfectly good example of a simple group. In fact, $C_p$ is for every prime $p$.

Comment: Certainly.  I am adding the restriction that nontrivial subgroups actually exist.

Comment: Well, you did say "Note that cyclic groups are no good."

Comment: Ah, I see where the misunderstanding is coming from.  The OP had added the restriction that nontrivial subgroups exist.  I'll edit my post to clear that up.

Answer (score 1):

A cyclic group of prime order has no subgroups except itself and the group with only one element.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Any subgroup of a commutative group is normal. What noncommutative groups do you know.

Bigger Hint: Think about subgroups of $S_5$.

Even Bigger Hint: What about the subgroup of the simple group $A_5$ generated by a product transpositions?

SUPER OMEGA HINT: What is $(12)(45)(12)(34)(12)(45)$?