# A sequence of subgroups tending to the trivial subgroup

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

Do you have an example of an abelian group $G$ with a sequence of mutually distinct nontrivial  subgroups $(A_n)$ such that 
$$\dots \le A_n\le\dots \le A_2\le A_1\le A_0=G$$
and
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\{1\}$$
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Mutually disjoint does not make sense for subgroups since all subgroups contain $1$.
2. If the abelian group is finite, then any decreasing sequence of subgroups is stationary. ie. $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_n = A_{n_0}$ for all $n\geq n_0$. Hence what you ask for is that $A_{n_0} = \{1\}$ for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. If the group is finitely generated and infinite, then it must contain $\mathbb{Z}$, in which case you can take the subgroups $A_n = (2^n)$

Comment: I think 1 should be editted out after I corrected a mistake in my question.

Answer (score 3):

This question becomes more interesting when you stipulate that the subgroups $A_i$ are of finite index in $G$. Your question then translates as,

> Does there exist an infinite, [residually finite](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group) abelian group?

The most obvious example is $\mathbb{Z}$, taking the subgroups to be $A_i=\langle n^i\rangle$, where $n$ is some fixed integer of absolute value greater than $1$.

I should point out that in this stronger setting you cannot simply say that "if your group contains a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ then it works" (although you can in the weaker setting, which is what the other answers do). For example, dispensing with the abelian condition for a second, the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(2, 3)=\langle a, t; t^{-1}a^2t=a^3\rangle$ contains elements of infinite order (for example, the element $t$ by Britton's lemma) but it is [not Hopfian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79852/does-g-cong-g-h-imply-that-h-is-trivial/79907#79907) so it is [not residually finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671399/an-example-of-a-residually-finite-group-which-is-not-hopf/672199#672199).

Now, it turns out that every finitely generated, abelian group works. That is, that every infinite, finitely-generated abelian group is residually finite. The following two exercises prove this.

**Exercise 1:** Prove that the following are equivalent for $G$ infinite:

- For every element $1\neq g\in G$ there exists a homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow F$ where $F$ is finite and $\phi(g)\neq 1_F$.
- $G$ is residually finite. That is, there exists a sequence of mutually distinct nontrivial subgroups $(A_n)$ *of finite index in* $G$ such that the following hold.
  $$\dots \le A_n\le\dots \le A_2\le A_1\le A_0=G$$
  $$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\{1\}$$

Use this to complete the following exercise.

**Exercise 2:** Prove that every finitely-generated abelian group is residually finite.

*Hints:*

1. Prove that if $H$ is residually finite then $G=H\times H$ is residually finite.
2. Prove that if $H$ is residually finite and $H$ has finite index in $G$ then $G$ is residually finite.
3. Apply the fundamental theorem for finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: thanks. It can  help me have more info about subgroups lattice of abelian groups.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$G= \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots$$ (or replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with any abelian group) and $$G_n= \underset{n \ \text{times}}{\underbrace{\{0\} \oplus \cdots  \oplus \{0\}}} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \cdots \leq G.$$

Then $ \cdots < G_2<G_1 < G_0=G$ and $\bigcap\limits_{n \geq 1} G_n =\{0\}$.

Comment: Inspiring‌‌‌‌‌!