# Noetherian implies Hopfian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, hopfian

Can someone provide me with a reference for the following 2 statements, or indicate a proof?

1. A finitely generated nilpotent group is Noetherian
2. A Noetherian group is Hopfian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first result can be found in Chapter 2.3 of Avinoam Mann's book [*How groups grow*](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/M_Mathematics/MA_Algebra/MAtg_Group%20theory/Mann%20A.%20How%20groups%20grow%20%28CUP,%202012%29%28ISBN%209781107657502%29%28O%29%28210s%29_MAtg_.pdf), LMS Lecture note series 395. The idea is to prove that in a finitely generated Nilpotent group there exists a central series $1=G_0<G_1<G_2<\cdots<G_i<\cdots<G_n=G$ where each factor $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is cyclic, and then use this to prove Noetherian.

The second result is, perhaps, more interesting. It is more interesting to me anyway! So:

Recall that a group is *Noetherian* if every subgroup is finitely generated. Equivalently, if every ascending chain of subgroups stabilises in finite length, that is, for every chain of subgroup $$H_1\leq H_2\leq H_3\leq\cdot$$ there exists some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $H_i=H_k$ for all $i>k$.

A group is *Hopfian* if it is not isomorphic to any of its proper quotients, so $G/N\not\cong G$ for $N\neq 1$.

**Theorem:** Noetherian $\Rightarrow$ Hopfian.

*Proof:* We shall prove that not-Hopfian implies not-Noetherian, which is sufficient. So, suppose that $G$ is not-Hopfian, so there exists a map $\phi: G\rightarrow G$ such that $\ker\phi\neq 1$. Let $N$ denote the kernel of $\phi$, $\ker\phi=N$, and more generally define $N_i:=\ker\phi^i$. Note that $\phi(N_{i+1})=N_i$. (This map is a very useful map when you are thinking about non-Hopfian groups. For another example of it, see Mal'cev's proof that [residually finite groups are Hopfian](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/672199/10513).)

The idea is to prove that the following chain does not stabilise after finitely many steps.
$$1=N_0<N_1<N_2<\cdots<N_i<\cdots$$
We prove that this does not stabilise by proving that $N_{i+1}/N_i\cong N\neq 1$ for all $i$. So, consider $N_{i+1}/N_i$. As $\ker\phi=N\leq N_i$ we can quotient out $N$ from both the top line and the bottom line and apply the third$^{[1]}$ isomorphism theorem to get the following isomorphism.
$$N_{i+1}/N_i\cong (N_{i+1}/N)/(N_i/N)$$
Now, by definition, $\phi(N_{i+1})=N_i$, and so $N_{i+1}/N=N_i$. Therefore, the above isomorphism implies that $N_{i+1}/N_i\cong N_i/N_{i-1}$. By induction, we thus have the following.
$$N_{i+1}/N_i\cong N$$
As $N$ is non-trivial, this implies that $N_{i}\lneq N_{i+1}$ for all $i$, and so this chain never stabilises. This proves the theorem.

$^{[1]}$Wikipedia claims it as the third, as does my favorite text. I thought it was the second. I will believe them though.

Answer (score 2):

The second statement can be found [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Noetherian_implies_Hopfian).

In particular, it uses two facts:

1. Noetherian implies ascending chain condition on normal subgroups.
2. Ascending chain condition on normal subgroups implies Hopfian.

More generally, see:

> Wehrfritz, B. A. F. (2009). The Basic Theory of Polycyclic Groups. In *Group and Ring Theoretic Properties of Polycyclic Groups* (pp. 13-28). Springer London.

**Theorem 2.13** (p. 20) proves that every finitely generated nilpotent group is polycyclic (i.e., Noetherian and solvable). The proof is attributed to Hirsch (1938).